# Angular 2: collapse multiple element

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have problem when I will collapse for content elements. When I press the button show all content are showing but no just one element of this content.

> I following by this example [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/oVoPIA0ZbMMauth812Ls/)

This is part of my html:

```
         <div *ngFor="#elem of apps">
               <div  class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                     <strong> {{elem.name}}</strong> on {{elem.host}} 
                  </div
                  <button type="button" (click)="isCollapsedContent= !isCollapsedContent">
               </div>
           </div>


           <div [collapse]="isCollapsedContent">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                   <thead>
                     <tr class="header">
                        <td>Property</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                     </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>app</td>
                         <td>{{elem.app}}</td>

                        <td>name</td>
                         <td>{{elem.name}}</td>

                        <td>host</td>
                         <td>{{elem.host}}</td>
                     </tr>
                   </tbody>
              </table>
           </div
```

And I add extra boolean property to my JSON from API called show default set false.

```
[
{"app":"database_1",
 "host":"my_host1",
 "name":"name1",
 "show": false
},
{"app":"database_2",
 "host":"my_host2",
 "name":"name2",
 "show": false
},
{"app":"database_3",
 "host":"my_host3",
 "name":"name3",
 "show": false
},
]
```

How can I show/hide only one element? Can I add property to isCollapsedContent for example:

```
<div [collapse]="isCollapsedContent(elem.show)">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ngIf to test whether elem.show is true.

```
  <div *ngFor="#elem of apps">
    <div  class="col-md-5">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <strong> {{elem.name}}</strong> on {{elem.host}} 
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="elem.show = !elem.show"></button>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover" *ngIf="elem.show">
      <thead>
        <td>app</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Host</td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td >{{elem.app}}</td>
          <td >{{elem.name}}</td>
          <td >{{elem.host}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: The div does not open when once collapsed.